# Pushing data from a UITableViewCell to a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, push

***I have a UISearchDisplaycontroller that i have to push information to text fields and need to link it to a navigation view controller.***

**Here is my code** -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    Recipe *recipe = nil;

    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        recipe = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.recipe = recipe;



}
```

}

Comment: what is issue in it? you are not getting correct indexpath?

Comment: the issue is when i link to a nav view it says push to nav view not supported.

Comment: May be ur navigation hierarchy wrong. U already have navigation to ur viewcontroller and again pushing to navigation controller. Final is ur navigation is at wrong place.

Comment: you have navigation controller before viewcontroller from which you are pushing to next vc

Answer (score 0):

Your UINavigationController heirarchy is wrong or it is wrongly placed.

Plz refer

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html