# Error Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

Tags: ios, xcode, push

***I have a UISearchDisplaycontroller that i have to push information to text fields and need to link it to a navigation view controller.***

**Here is the error -**

```
   2014-12-10 20:05:08.775 Contents Concepts Mobile[2785:333301] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2311dc1f 0x30b96c8b 0x26663207 0x268d0229 0x26662b43 0x266f2f67 0x267a4c0f 0x26656c4d 0x265d2aab 0x230e43b5 0x230e1a73 0x230e1e7b 0x23030211 0x23030023 0x2a3c00a9 0x2663c1d1 0xf0225 0x31116aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**Here is my code** -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    Recipe *recipe = nil;

    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        recipe = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.recipe = recipe;



}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to push a navigation controller onto another navigation controller?

Comment: No, i am trying to push a table view controller to a navigationview controller

Comment: So you're pushing a navigation view controller? "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported"

Comment: Yes correct. I am trying to push a navigation controller but i do not know how to do it.

Comment: You can't. Like the error says, "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported."

Comment: ok, so how do i get the information from one tableview controller to another

Comment: @mattsuff You are asking same que two times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393433/pushing-data-from-a-uitableviewcell-to-a-uinavigationcontroller?rq=1 don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post your story board setting as well. It seems you have a linking problem between two different views. Cause the error message said you are trying to push the navigation controller and not the view controller.

Comment: i posted an image of my storyboard here. http://s1302.photobucket.com/user/mattsuff1/media/ScreenShot2014-12-10at81933PM_zpsa29e0116.png.html

Comment: The table view controllers that im using are in the right of the corner. They are the 3 controllers.

Comment: You cannot push navigation controller to another navigation controller. You can only push viewcontroller to navigation controller.

Comment: currently i am trying to push a table view controller to another table view controller but that wasnt working either

Comment: They are the two table view controllers in the top right of the image

Comment: I think you can try to download the sample project UICatelog 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710

to learn how they transit the tableviewcontroller to another view controller.

It probably you have some incorrect segue settings in your storyboard.

Comment: I downloaded the tutorial and the cells are static cells, becuase i will be using a search bar on my table view controller i will need the cells to be prototype

Comment: If you don't mind, can you upload your project to a public place. So that I can download and check tonight.

Comment: Where would i be able to upload the project to?

Comment: For example, you can zip your project and upload to dropbox public folder. Copy the url link and pm / email me.

Comment: Okay i uploaded it to files.com, let me know if you can access it. http://www.files.com/set/548a465c8cb15

Comment: Got it, I will check it after work.

Comment: Hi some of your classes are missing in your zip file (ReciptTableViewController, RecipeTableCell, RecipeDetailViewController, Recipe, RecipeBookViewController). Can you zip again.

Besides, Can you tell me which class will trigger the exception? Thanks.